# accidently applied mirror modifier

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

hi all so I have been working on a character here , I used mirror modifier , after a while I accidently applied the mirror modifier on the character , I did not want to apply it , because I Also Want to rig the character , without the mirror modifier I don t think IM  Able to use x y z for the rig? is there a way so I can Redo it Manually ? thanks in advance[image]

Comment: You can delete half of the mesh and give it back the Mirror modifier, but what you mean with the XYZ for the rig?

Comment: sorry didnt explain much , i meant when you  rig a character you cant use the X axis so you can disable for example the other left hand bone , so i can use 1 bone not the other basically a mirror

Comment: the mesh and the armature are 2 different things, you'll be able to use the symmetrize option of your armature even if the mesh has its mirror applied if this is your question

Comment: ohh okay thank you moonboots always helpful for the tips , as  im actually still new at rigging , best regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mesh and the armature are 2 different things, you'll be able to use the symmetrize option of your armature even if the mesh has its mirror applied.